# Handsontable implementation in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, handsontable

I am very much impressed with handsontable functionality. I tried to implement this in Oracle ADF. This functionality working fine with `.jsp` file but the data is not rendering in `.jspx` file.

Can we integrate this handsontable functionality Oracle ADF framework? Could you please suggest how to achieve the same in ADF?

1. I have created the Adf application in Jdeveloper 11.1.1.7 version
2. I have created the .jspx file with the following code

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
  <f:view>
    <af:document id="d1">
      <af:form id="f1">
        <af:resource type="javascript" source="jquery.min.js"/>
        <af:resource type="javascript" source="jquery.handsontable.full.js"/>
        <link href="jquery.handsontable.full.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <div id="dataTable"/>
        <af:resource type="javascript">
         var data = [
            ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
            ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
            ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
            ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
          ];
          $("#dataTable").handsontable({
            data: data,
            minSpareRows: 1,
            startRows: 6,
            startCols: 8
          });

        </af:resource>
      </af:form>
    </af:document>
  </f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

1. when I try run the .jspx file data is not rendering.

Comment: `I tried to implement this in Oracle ADF` - Can you show some code of **what** you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi Andreas, I have created one jspx file and in the jspx file  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
<f:view>
<af:document id="d1">
<af:form id="f1">
<af:resource type="javascript" source="jquery.min.js"/>
<af:resource type="javascript" source="jquery.handsontable.full.js"/>
<link href="jquery.handsontable.full.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

Comment: <div id="dataTable"/>
<af:resource type="javascript">
     var data = [
        ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
        ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
        ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
        ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
      ];
      $("#dataTable").handsontable({
        data: data,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        startRows: 6,
        startCols: 8
      });

</af:resource>
  </af:form>
  </af:document>
  </f:view>
</jsp:root>
Its showing the empty data

Comment: Please add the code to your question - you can edit it. Code in comments is really hard to read

Comment: Hi Andreas,I tried to edit, but its skipping all the elements and just displaying the "var data = [ ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"], ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13], ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13], ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13] ]; $("#dataTable").handsontable({ data: data, minSpareRows: 1, startRows: 6, startCols: 8 });"

Answer (score 0):

Please add a script tag.

`<script>
    var data = [
            ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
            ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
            ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
            ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
          ];
          $("#dataTable").handsontable({
            data: data,
            minSpareRows: 1,
            startRows: 6,
            startCols: 8
          });
</script>`